# Migration Swift 2.1 to Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, swift2

I'm having trouble translating the code in Swift 2.1 to Swift 3.0. I'm finding error on the block "lazy var" (line 3 and 4). The error message: "Instance member 'çontentView'cannot be used on the type 'MyView'".

But the code in Swift 2.1 works.

Can someone help me?

My code:

@IBDesignable
class MyView: UIView {

```
private lazy var __once: () = { () -> Void in
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))

    MyView.contentView = UINib(nibName: "MyView", bundle: bundle).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    MyView.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.addSubview(MyView.contentView)

    let view = ["contentView": MyView.contentView]
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[contentView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: view))
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[contentView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: view))

    MyView.titleMyLabel.text = MyView.myTitle
    MyView.descriptionMyLabel.text = MyView.myDescription
    MyView.mobileNumberLabel.text = MyView.numberMobile
    MyView.myBarBotton.botaoMudou(.hight)
    MyView.myBarBotton.botaoMudou(.left)
    MyView.myBarBotton.botaoMudou(.center)

    self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}()

@IBInspectable var myTitle: String? {
    didSet {
        titleMyLabel.text = myTitle
    }
}
@IBInspectable var myDescription: String? {
    didSet {
        descriptionMyLabel.text = myDescription
    }
}
@IBInspectable var numberMobile: String? {
    didSet {
        mobileNumberLabel.text = numberMobile
    }
}

@IBInspectable var rawStyleLeftButton: Int {
    set(newValue) {
        myBarBotton.rawstyleLeftButton = newValue
    }
    get {
        return myBarBotton.rawstyleLeftButton
    }
}
@IBInspectable var rawStyleHightButton: Int {
    set(newValue) {
        myBarBotton.rawstyleHightButton = newValue
    }
    get {
        return myBarBotton.rawstyleHightButton
    }
}
@IBInspectable var rawStyleCenterButton: Int {
    set(newValue) {
        myBarBotton.rawstyleCenterButton = newValue
    }
    get {
        return myBarBotton.rawstyleCenterButton
    }
}

@IBInspectable var titleLeftButtom: String? {
    set(newValue) {
        myBarBotton.myTitleBotaoEsquerdo = newValue
    }
    get {
        return myBarBotton.myTitleBotaoEsquerdo
    }
}
@IBInspectable var titleCenterButtom: String? {
    set(newValue) {
        myBarBotton.myTitleBotaoCentral = newValue
    }
    get {
        return myBarBotton.myTitleBotaoCentral
    }
}
@IBInspectable var titleHightButton: String? {
    set(newValue) {
        myBarBotton.myTitleBotaoDireito = newValue
    }
    get {
        return myBarBotton.myTitleBotaoDireito
    }
}

var styleLeftButton: styleMyBarBotton {
    set(newValue) {
        myBarBotton.styleLeftButton = newValue
    }
    get {
        return myBarBotton.styleLeftButton
    }
}
var styleCenterButton: styleMyBarBotton {
    set(newValue) {
        myBarBotton.styleCenterButton = newValue
    }
    get {
        return myBarBotton.styleCenterButton
    }
}
var styleHightButton: styleMyBarBotton {
    set(newValue) {
        myBarBotton.styleHightButton = newValue
    }
    get {
        return myBarBotton.styleHightButton
    }
}

fileprivate var token: Int = 0
fileprivate var contentView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var myBarBotton: myBarBottonView!
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var titleMyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var descriptionMyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var mobileNumberLabel: UILabel!


fileprivate func initialization() {
    _ = self.__once
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initialization()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initialization()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After changing MyView to self at each line with an error, using below code, your class compiled without an error in a Playground.

```
private lazy var __once: () = { () -> Void in [weak self]
        guard let strongSelf = self else{return}
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: strongSelf))

        strongSelf.contentView = UINib(nibName: "MyView", bundle: bundle).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        strongSelf.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        strongSelf.addSubview(strongSelf.contentView)

        let view = ["contentView": strongSelf.contentView]
        strongSelf.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[contentView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: view))
        strongSelf.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[contentView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: view))

        strongSelf.titleMyLabel.text = MyView.myTitle
        strongSelf.descriptionMyLabel.text = MyView.myDescription
        strongSelf.mobileNumberLabel.text = MyView.numberMobile
        MyView.myBarBotton.botaoMudou(.hight)
        MyView.myBarBotton.botaoMudou(.left)
        MyView.myBarBotton.botaoMudou(.center)

        strongSelf.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    }()
```